# Importing a SharePoint 2013 workflow in Visual Studio

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, 2013, visual-studio, designer-workflow

I'm creating a simple workflow in Visual Studio:
[image]

I can deploy it, and it works. I then try to open it with SharePoint designer:
[image]
However, the steps/activities/stages are missing. How come I'm not seeing the sequence I've created in Visual Studio in the designer? Shouldn't I see at least an IF statement?

Additionally, it does not work when I try it vice versa. Steps I took:

1. Created a simple workflow **in sharepoint designer**.
2. Opened Visual Studio and attempted to "Import a SharePoint 2013 project" because ***somehow***, you can only import SharePoint 2010 reusable workflows, not SharePoint 2013 reusable workflows.[image]
3. Visual Studio fails to open it.
   [image]

I can't even find anything relevant on Google. This seems like a huge omission to me. Tutorials such as [this one](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee231580.aspx) on MSDN explain how to import a SharePoint **2010** workflow into Visual Studio 2012. Not a Sharepoint 2013 into Visual Studio 2012. Can anyone explain what's going on?

Comment: David, I know this thread is really, really old but did you ever manage to get this to work? I have a client who may lose all of their workflows because their WF farm is hosed but I can still pull out the workflow.xaml files. If I could import those into VS even just to get a visual representation then I would be a total hero. I'll even play Robin and you can be Batman in this story lol

Comment: @Newclique I want to help you but I really can't remember :( My feeling was that after 2 days of tearing my hair I'd figured it's not possible. Thankfully I've moved away from Sharepoint - I don't miss those days!

Comment: Thanks, David. I'll tell you what, it is definitely possible. The trick it getting the namespaces to match. Pull down the workflow.xaml from SharePoint and compare it in a text editor to a new workflow you make in a VS SharePoint workflow project. With some fiddling around, at the very least you can render out the graphical design of a WF using VS. This might be enough to salvage a WF that didn't get exported to a template using SPD. You know, next new farm I have to do maintenance on, first thing I'll do is walk through each WF and click Export Template in SPD!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workflow activities/actions are in separate assemblies, and each tool references a different one.

I have some tips on my site (http://www.schaeflein.net/setting-workflow-status-in-visual-studio-and-sharepoint-designer/) about referencing the SPD actions in VS. However, making changes to the SPD workflow in VS is not something that is advertised as an option.

I have successfully included an SPD workflow in a Sandboxed solution, but I did not make changes.

Comment: Do you know of any way to convert List workflow (SP2013) from SPD to a visual studio workflow?

Comment: I tried a long time ago, and determined it is not possible.

Comment: It's definitely possible. See my comment above.